# Program seems to ignore rest of the list

Tags: c#, foreach

I am trying to make retrieve a certain string from a list of object in c#( let's call that list userlist)(the list has about 1600 elements in it and each object has about 15 different parameters).
So this is the code that I have:

```
 private List<String> getGameList(CommandEventArgs e) {
        List<String> allgames = new List<string>();
        List<User> userlist = e.Server.Users.ToList();
        foreach (User u in userlist)
        {
            if (u.CurrentGame.ToString() != "")
            {
                if (u.CurrentGame.Value.Name != null)
                {
                    allgames.Insert(0, u.CurrentGame.Value.Name);


                }

            }

        }

        return allgames;


    }
```

But it everytime that this bit of code runs the list that gets returned has only one or two results in it while it should retrieve a lot more.

To give more information about the code:

- User is the object with about 15 parameters/objects under it
- u.CurrentGame retrieves an object called "Game" that is under a "User"
- u.CurrentGame.Value.Name is the string that I want to retrieve and add in the new "allgames" list
- I know the Insert(0,String) is strange but for some reason a simple .Add didn't seem to work properly either

Any idea why I only have 1 or 2 results and not more while it should?
I can definitly provide more information if needed.

Thank you

Comment: What problem you face with `allgames.Add`? Did you debug the code and see how many times it inserts value to the list? Are you sure `u.CurrentGame.ToString()` and `u.CurrentGame.Value.Name` is not null for all the users?

Comment: You're going to have to insert breakpoints at each if() to see what expected result is failing and draw conclusions from there.

Comment: Objects don't have parameters. *"an object called "Game" that is under a "User""* is nonsensical. Please say what you actually mean. You could easily find out what's happening by putting in a breakpoint at the start of the loop and stepping through it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am sure that for certain users those values are not null. For the allgames.Add() when I use that it gives me an invalid operation exception but with the allgames.Insert() it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the complete code my guess is that you either have an early `return` or a `break` somewhere in your loop where you probably should have been using a `continue` instead to *continue* iterating through the list.

You should also probably be using `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)` instead of the comparison with `""`.

That's all the help I can give with the information you've provided.

Comment: you can see the whole methode. There is mention of a break anywhere in that methode. I have been putting breakpoint and after it found on results it jumps out of the foreach loop and goes to the return which is outside of the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I did small experiment 3 cases, and all 3 cases works somehow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace p44785433
{
class Program
{
    static List<User> userList = UserFactory.GenerateUsers();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number Of Users: {0}", userList.Count);
        var x = getGameList(userList); // 1600 on output
        var y = getGameListUpdated(userList); // 1600< on output depend of randomized empty name
        var z = getGameListLinq(userList); // 1600< on output depend of randomized empty name
    }

    private static List<String> getGameList(List<User>  parUserList)
    {
        List<string> allgames = new List<string>();
        List<User> userlist = /*e.Server.Users.ToList();*/ parUserList;
        foreach (User u in userlist)
        {
            if (u.CurrentGame.ToString() != "")
            {
                if (u.CurrentGame.Value.Name != null)
                {
                    allgames.Insert(0, u.CurrentGame.Value.Name);
                }
            }
        }

        return allgames;
    }

    private static List<String> getGameListUpdated(List<User> parUserList)
    {
        List<string> allgames = new List<string>();
        List<User> userlist = /*e.Server.Users.ToList();*/ parUserList;
        foreach (User u in userlist)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.CurrentGame.ToString()))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.CurrentGame.Value.Name))
                {
                    allgames.Insert(0, u.CurrentGame.Value.Name);
                }
            }
        }

        return allgames;
    }

    private static List<String> getGameListLinq(List<User> parUserList)
    {            
        List<User> userlist = /*e.Server.Users.ToList();*/ parUserList;
        var x = userList.Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.CurrentGame.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.CurrentGame.Value.Name)); // remove empty
        var y = x.Select(r => r.CurrentGame.Value.Name); // select strings
        var z = y.Reverse(); // reverse order instead of insert

        return z.ToList();
    }
}

internal class User
{
    public Game CurrentGame { get; set; }
    public string Par1 { get; set; }
    public string Par2 { get; set; }
    public string Par3 { get; set; }
    public string Par4 { get; set; }
    public string Par5 { get; set; }
    public string Par6 { get; set; }
    public string Par7 { get; set; }
    public string Par8 { get; set; }
    public string Par9 { get; set; }
    public string Par10 { get; set; }
    public string Par11 { get; set; }
    public string Par12 { get; set; }
    public string Par13 { get; set; }
    public string Par14 { get; set; }

    internal static User CreateDummy()
    {
        return  new User()
        {
            CurrentGame = Game.CreateDummy(),
            Par6 = UserFactory.Rnd.NextDouble().ToString(),
            Par12 = UserFactory.Rnd.NextDouble().ToString()
        };
    }
}


internal static class UserFactory
{
    static Random _rnd;
    internal static Random Rnd
    {
        get
        {
            if (_rnd == null) _rnd = new Random();
            return _rnd;
        }
    }
    internal static List<User> GenerateUsers()
    {
        List<User> list = new List<User>();

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)1600; i++)
        {
            list.Add(User.CreateDummy());
        }

        return list;
    }
}

internal class Game
{
    public Value Value { get; set; }

    public string Par1 { get; set; }
    public string Par2 { get; set; }
    public string Par3 { get; set; }
    public string Par4 { get; set; }
    public string Par5 { get; set; }
    public string Par6 { get; set; }
    public string Par7 { get; set; }
    public string Par8 { get; set; }
    public string Par9 { get; set; }
    public string Par10 { get; set; }
    public string Par11 { get; set; }
    public string Par12 { get; set; }
    public string Par13 { get; set; }
    public string Par14 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Par6;
    }

    internal static Game CreateDummy()
    {
        return new Game()
        {
            Value = Value.CreateDummy(),
            Par6 = UserFactory.Rnd.NextDouble().ToString(),
            Par12 = UserFactory.Rnd.NextDouble().ToString()
        };
    }
}

internal class Value
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Par1 { get; set; }
    public string Par2 { get; set; }
    public string Par3 { get; set; }
    public string Par4 { get; set; }
    public string Par5 { get; set; }
    public string Par6 { get; set; }
    public string Par7 { get; set; }
    public string Par8 { get; set; }
    public string Par9 { get; set; }
    public string Par10 { get; set; }
    public string Par11 { get; set; }
    public string Par12 { get; set; }
    public string Par13 { get; set; }
    public string Par14 { get; set; }

    internal static Value CreateDummy()
    {
        return new Value()
        {
            Name = (UserFactory.Rnd.Next(10)!=0 ? string.Format("XXA{0}XAA", UserFactory.Rnd.NextDouble()): string.Empty),
            Par5 = UserFactory.Rnd.NextDouble().ToString(),
            Par11 = UserFactory.Rnd.NextDouble().ToString()
        };
    }
}
```

}